# What is the correct XTERM/ANSI sequence for (mouse) wheel and or scroll, preferably that doesnt require X,Y coordinates?

Tags: ansi-escape, xtermjs

On my xterm.js terminal, I have touchmove events to send cursor-keys by swipe, and scroll/wheel by swiping left and bottom edges (for terminal 'application mode').  The cursor-keys-swipe works great, but I can't seem to find effective codes for mouse-wheel or scroll.  For now I'm using two or four cursor-key-codes in opposing direction to mimic wheel/scroll on the edges, and it's ok, but not quite the behaviour I want.  It should scroll line-by-line, only moving the text vertically, not the cursor.

An example of the behaviour I'm looking for is the Termux terminal app for Android, which sends mouse-wheel xterm/ansi codes when swiping up or down in 'application mode'.  Details...

Test setup is Midnight Commander in Bash, using xterm.js and Termux, 'cat -A' or 'sed -n l' to get visuals for non-printables.

In Termux, ssh to a server with MC installed.  Run 'mc'.  Abruptly disconnect by turning off wifi or other method.  Run 'cat -A' or 'sed -n l'.  Swipe up and down.  You should get symbols for mouse-wheel 'ANSI' codes (apparently an xterm protocol actually).  Like these:

^[[<65;82;14M
^[[<64;83;12M

My understanding is this should mean "\x1b[<65;82;14M", and "\x1b[<64;83;12M", respectively, and the second and third numbers are X,Y 'pointer' coordinates (in 'characters').  But even cut-and-paste, replacing the '^[' with a literal Escape, doesnt seem to work.

I've looked through a ton of documents on ANSI and Xterm codes for wheel or scroll, but can't seem to find anything that works.

What am I missing here?  Is the alligator bracket literal?  Does it symbolize something else?  As-is, I get no apparent reaction from xterm.js.  Take it out, I get the remainder of the code printed out each time the event fires.

I also tried various sequences for scrolling, advance/negative line index/LF from a number of terminal types, but so far none produce scrolling in Midnight Commander or other utilities that use 'application mode' or the 'alternate screen buffer'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I found I had to supply the xterm-sequences for mouse scroll with live cell coordinates (by row and column) for Button 4 and 5 release events. I.E.:

```
sock.send("\x1b[<65;"+xcol+';'+yrow+'M');  // SCROLL UP '[<65'
```

or

```
sock.send("\x1b[<64;"+xcol+';'+yrow+'M');  // SCROLL DN '[<64'
```

I found other working codes for scroll behavior but they work mainly outside of application mode.  "\x1b", "\u001b", and "\033" all match() identically with Escape.  xcol and yrow are required live "pointer" coordinates on the terminal in cells, not pixels.  Sending static coordinates does not seem to work.  Benchmark tests included checking for mouse-wheel response in Midnight Commander, mcedit, less, and bash.

In the xterm.js source, there is the code to do this for a real mouse.  I got the touchmove event coordinates and translated them into character cell coordinates using a variation of this, then sent them through the websocket via one of these two codes periodically, based on location along a swipe gesture.  This effectively emulated a mouse-wheel event on the server, allowing scroll in xterm's 'application mode' for touch.

A further enhancement is to detect application mode, and send up and down arrows instead when not in it.

Screenshot of actual working code, highlighting px to cell coordinate conversion, and xterm mouse-wheel sequences:
[image]

Addendum:  Screenshot and URL for pageX/pageY conversion to col/row for sending xterm sgr mouse events.

http://docs.xtermjs.org/src_xterm.js.html
[image]

Comment: Hey, did you happen to find the control sequences for the left and right scroll wheel buttons?

Comment: Good question.  I think they may not be in the protocol.  If they are they are probably ESC+66 and ESC+67, plus the mouse coords in cols/rows.  The scroll-up/down wheel movements are buttons 4 and 5 to xterm, so if it supports left/right they would be considered buttons 6 and 7.  Like this pattern for up-scroll "button":  ("\x1b[<65;" + touchmoveXcol + ';' + touchmoveYrow + 'M') except replace 65 with 66 or 67.  You can derive the column/row coords by dividing position in pixels by the number of rows (for y) or cols (for x) your terminal has.  Let us all know if this works!

Comment: Apologies btw, if I'm being redundant, just want to be sure you have all the details to work with.  Thanks for the thumbs up also.

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble for a detailed reply! That's pretty much what I thought, though using octal `\033` in place of hex `\x1b`, but it didn't work - nor did several other values apart from 66 and 67. My guess is it's a mode thing - your answer mentions `application mode`, and looking at terminal emulator source code, there's a *heap* of standards and protocols. In vim insert mode, you can press control-v, and scroll with a mousewheel, to see what char sequence vim received.

Comment: I don't have a PC (or a wheel mouse), but trying to simulate it with touch events on a phone (trying to modify the terminal emulator termux.com). Scroll up/down works (i.e. moving a finger down or up), but a curious thing is one build shows sequences like yours above, and another shows sequences like `^[[MaN&` and  `^[[M\`O'` for up down... checking again just now, it's back to your method... I'm guessing my mucking around with different escape sequences before put it in a different mode...

Comment: Wow, nice @hyperpallium!  That's exactly what I started with and although it's the best, termux still left some things to be desired, plus I wanted to write a web-based terminal with extra capabilities.  Yeah, it's definitely one of the difficult things in experimenting with terminal escape sequences.  If memory serves the one ending with an O is an arrow key.  But yeah, come of the codes change depending on mode, or if your in certain apps-- Midnight Commander for instance.

Comment: I noticed some of the code was the same as termux, but wasn't sure if that was just from `terminal emulator` that termux is based on! When I first came across terminal escape codes I stayed away as far possible, it looks so confusing and complicated. The source covers so many standards, it makes me think it would be great to cut through it all and start fresh. But it's a public API now, and you'd lose all that software that relies on it. Oh, and [xkcd/927](https://xkcd.com/927/).

Comment: I've now gone through vim's source, and it does not detect left/right mouse wheel events in the terminal (only in the GUI). I wrote it up [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/16940/3189) and included my screen-size motivation - I just noticed your screenshots are of phones, so maybe this is relevant to you, too?

Comment: Yes, xkcd-- there should be 16 competing standards just to make it divide evenly in hex format. ;)  Yeah the phone thing was a big deal for me.  I used termux as an example of the touch/swipe functionality I was going for and built up from there.  Mine is a node.js web-app ssh terminal.  I used xterm.js as a base for the front-end and web-sockets to pipe io between it and the server.  One idea, if you can't get the left-right scroll is to use codes for arrow keys.

Comment: I just looked it up in my code.  That's what I did, so left/right swipe sends arrows.  "\x1bOD" is left arrow;  "\x1bOC" is right arrow (this is in application mode, I think, where you would normally need it).  If you need them, corresponding Up/Down arrows are "x1bOA" and "x1bOB" respective-- those are O's just for clarity, in case it's hard to distinguish on your display.  "\x1b" is Escape, in case you need to know-- there are a lot of ways of sending an excape though.

Comment: My term is all in JavaScript since it's a web-app, but if your in C/C++ or whatever should be easy to translate, if necessary.  I set mine up with a resize function same as termux, though you can also use the +/- buttons in the oval at the bottom right.  That part was a bit more complicated.  The scroll thing should detect either SGR on/off signals or Apllication mode signals (I think I used the former in the end, don't remember), and change to arrows or default native scroll-action so when your at a regular command-prompt it uses normal, local scrolling.

Comment: Also, to keep it from trying to do local native scrolling and sending mouse-scroll-codes at the same time, when in SGR/Application mode I used an event.stopPropagation() and an event.preventDefault() .  For some reason it needed both.

Comment: Your app sounds cool, you could use it on mobile to ssh into the same phone.

Comment: `application mode`: I finally looked this up. It's an alternative to `normal mode` that changes the escape sequences sent by special keys on extended keyboards (keypad, arrow keys, scroll keys). `normal mode` sequences begin `^[[` (called `CSI`); `application mode` sequences with `^[O` (called `SS3`).

Comment: Do I understand correctly that when you send left/right arrow keys for  left/right swipes, this is a cursor movement left/right - and not a scroll left/right? I tested it in vim on termux with `tmux send-keys`, and that's what it does (but termux and/or tmux might change it). You may know that in vim, `zh` and `zl` are scroll left/right, with cursor not moving (named for `h` and `l` cursor left/right). With some swapping that I'm ignoring here. Are `application mode` left/right supposed to scroll left/right?

Comment: I've made up some control codes - like the vimdocs do for [xterm-mouse-wheel](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html#xterm-mouse-wheel) (for <ScrollWheelUp> and <ScrollWheelDown>), and then map those to `zl` and `zh`. But I don't like this, because it requires the user to add these mappings. I'd like it to just work.

Comment: Yes, @hyp.  I'm sending the terminal esape codes for arrow keys though.  My terminal tack is generally something like ssh+xterm+tmux+midnight commander.  When I open tmux I set TERM to 'xterm-color' (might have changed that to 'screen-color' as recommended by the specs, but if I remember this resulted in broken compatibility on some systems).

Comment: Yeah, a couple things I had to kind of backwards-reverse-engineer like that.  Since mine is a web-app, there's a little more control server-side before it actually hits sshd since I had to write the back-end as well.  Basically it the front-end sends the data through a web-socket, hits a nodejs-based web-server, and then is sent through ssh/sshd.  A few things had to be caught and modded on the way otherwise they get lost in translation-- not totally sure why but I think it's in the ssh2 node module.

Comment: So, when you swipe left/right, the cursor moves left/right? (In vim's `:set nowrap`, it will scroll horizontally when it gets to the left/right edges.)

Comment: Correct.  Back to Midnight Commander, if your in the editor with a bunch of text it will move the cursor.  If your in the file viewer it will move the view if you are set to not wrap text and you have lines longer than the terminal's width in columns.

Answer (score 1):

That's several questions:

- the "alligator bracket" is not *literal*.  That's two characters <kbd>*Escape*</kbd><kbd>**`[`**</kbd>, because ASCII *escape* commonly is printed as **`^[`**.
- in alternate screen, your terminal may send only up/down cursor escapes rather than xterm's SGR-mode (the sequence ending with **`M`**).
- changing **`TERM`** shouldn't affect how the mouse works, although some applications are known to have hard-coded behavior based on that variable.

Comment: Yes, effectively ("\x1b" + '[<65;82;14M'), sends an actual escape character to the server.  The '<' was an actual '<' though.  I had to add an algorithm to get the touchmoves location by cell and send them in the escape sequence, like ("\x1b[<65;" + touchmoveXcol + ';' + touchmoveYrow + 'M').  It just takes a lot more code, cause you have to translate from px to cells.  I was hoping for a couple short static sequences.  It actually is better though.  Sending xterm mouse codes is just like using a real mouse to it, so you're remote cli app will respond identically when fired off by touch.

Comment: I see: the **`<`** is part of the protocol, denoting the sequence as a *private* control sequence.  That "use CSI **<** followed" in [XTerm Control Sequences](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Extended-coordinates) is not a typo.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Xterm transmits mouse-events via their own little ansi-style control-sequence mini-protocol.  Basically, denoting button number, click or release, and cell coordinates.  In this case, mouse-wheel is considered buttons 4 and 5, released.  "\x1b[<65" for up, "\x1b[<64" for down.  Once I hooked it up to live cell coordinates it seamless.

Comment: In relation to modes like you mentioned, most xterm's I've used send the above two sequences for real mouse-wheel events in Midnight Commander, but send sequences for cursor arrow keys when at a regular command prompt.  I believe the terminal normally detects whether it's in 'application mode' or not to determine which codes to send in either context.  Right now it works in MC, but prints the sequence out at regular command prompt.  Should I check for 'application mode' to determine when to send arrows keys?  Or something else, like one that tells it to use SGR??

Comment: There's **xterm** and **imitators** (not to confuse the two).

Comment: True, lol.  Only problem I have with Xterm proper is it's platform-dependent.  Why I got into xterm.js.  It's portable, and with a few mods can be great for dev, especially if you do remote work using a variety of devices, or are working over a tenuous connection, firewalls, etc.  I do most of my programming straight from my phone, so this makes it real convienient since I can login from pretty much anything, anywhere, and get straight back to where I was using the same terminal whether on pc, phone, or tab.