# How to catch user scroll action in the terminal?

Tags: c, vim, terminal, command-line

For example, on `vim`, when you scroll, it knows to move the cursor up and down, but so far, following [this tutorial](https://github.com/snaptoken/kilo-tutorial), scrolling will take you off the page of the editor.

For example, you can note that the following code is unable to catch the scroll action, and the terminal simply scrolls:

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct termios orig_termios;

void
disable_raw_mode (void)
{
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &orig_termios);
}

void
enable_raw_mode (void)
{
  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &orig_termios);
  atexit(disable_raw_mode);

  struct termios raw = orig_termios;
  raw.c_iflag &= ~(BRKINT | INPCK | PARMRK | INLCR | IGNCR | ISTRIP | ICRNL | IXON);
  raw.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST);
  raw.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON | IEXTEN | ISIG);
  raw.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB);
  raw.c_cflag |= (CS8);


  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &raw);
}

int
main (void)
{
  enable_raw_mode();
  
  char c;
  while ( read(STDIN_FILENO,  &c, 1) == 1 )
    {
      if (iscntrl(c))
        printf("%d\n", c);
      else
        printf("%d ('%c')\n", c, c);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks like it should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46627983/what-is-the-correct-xterm-ansi-sequence-for-mouse-wheel-and-or-scroll-prefera

Comment: Let me specify further. I am unable to currently catch them. I'll provide some code.

Comment: As I understand it, it just sends escape sequences similar to the up and down arrows. Can you catch those?

Comment: Up down is catchable @Barmar. Try the program I just posted if you'd like to see. Scroll actions and things like `PageUp` and `PageDown` are not.

Comment: I think you may need to go into the alternate screen, so it doesn't just do the scrolling in the terminal emulator's scrollback buffer.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, I'm able to using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188508/how-curses-preserves-screen-contents) answer, but scrolling still occurs, despite the alternate screen.

Comment: You can see this yourself by running `tput smcup` and scrolling and the scroll action remains not catchable. If you run `vi`, you can use the scroll bar to scroll away from it, but `vi` itself catches the the scroll action.

Comment: Use `script` to start a transcript, run `vim` or `less`, and do some scrolling. Exit script and view the transcript file with `cat -v transcript`. You'll see the escape sequences that vim or less sends to the terminal to enable this feature.

Comment: I wasn't able to find anything @Barmar. What I am finding is that some terminals send key events for mouse scroll in alternate screen, but this is not true for me.

Comment: If it works for `vim` then it has to be sending escape sequences, since it has no direct access to the mouse.

Comment: I was finally able to find it [here](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Mouse-Tracking) @Barmar. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find anything on a standardized set of escape sequences it would send back. I also can't find the same codes I used anywhere in the `vim` log.